# Eclipse ADT Plugin Api 24 and 25 issue

Tags: android, eclipse, android-api-levels

Hello i'm using eclipse neon and my problem is that in android sdk manager when im trying to install new packages i have selected api 24 and 25, i click install packages and when i get to licens agreement it says :

```
Package 'ARM 64 v8a System Image, Android API 24, revision 7' depends on 'Missing SDK Platform Android, API 24'.
Package 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 25, revision 2' depends on 'Missing SDK Platform Android, API 25'
```

I reloaded the packages and cleared the cache still doesn't fix.
How can i fix this ? Thanks.

Comment: use android studio

Comment: any other ideas... i use eclipse a lot dont want to move to android studio.

Comment: You HAVE to move to android studio, google are no longer supporting the ADT plugin which is why it cant find 24 and 25

Comment: read this http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/11/02/google-officially-ends-support-for-eclipse-android-developer-tools-in-favor-of-android-studio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must move to Android Studio.

Google are no longer supporting the ADT plugin which is why it cant find API 24 or 25, see this blog post for more information:

http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/11/02/google-officially-ends-support-for-eclipse-android-developer-tools-in-favor-of-android-studio/

Comment: Than why on my pc where i have installed adt plugin months ago it finds the api 24 and 25 and on my laptop when i'm trying to install now the plugin doesn't find it anymore ?

Comment: I dont know, but the fact still remains, you need to move to android studio

Comment: Google is no longer supporting the ADT plugin, and it is actively encouraging developers to migrate to Android Studio. Is the Eclipse Foundation still supporting and encouraging Developers to use Eclipse ADT for Android development, or did even the Eclipse Foundation give up and abandon Eclipse ADT? I am wondering if Android Studio and Eclipse ADT are still competitors, or if Eclipse ADT was defeated and they just gave up. It is obvious that Google wants everyone to use Android Studio, but what is the position of the Eclipse Foundation about that?